# Posting code in answers and copyright statement?

Tags: ros, answers.ros.org

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Is it appropriate to post a program listing as an answer to a question? (there is a "preformatted text" tool to assist with this)

When posting code for ROS here or elsewhere, should the Willow Garage copyright/limitations notice always be included?

(I have some pointcloud to laserscan code I can share)

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/9754/posting-code-in-answers-and-copyright-statement?/) by [Bart](https://answers.ros.org/users/286/bart/) on ROS Answers with karma: 856 on 2011-04-17

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is a preformatted text icon to post this. (only layout wise)

Depending on the copyright issue, according to me this depend on the license of the particular code snippet. For large code part I prefer to link to the location, instead of copy/paste.

---

Originally posted by [KoenBuys](https://answers.ros.org/users/134/koenbuys/) with karma: 2314 on 2011-04-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1